# Access to fetch at <my-google-cloud-function> from origin 'https://www.reddit.com' has been blocked ... CORS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-functions, cors, gsutil

I am working on a Google Chrome extension to block a subset of images from posts in a user's Reddit feed based on some backend computer vision run in Python in Google Cloud Storage. The Python code takes a single argument (the URL of an image in Reddit), which is passed in JavaScript via:

```
const api_url = https://<my-google-chrome-url>

var curUrl = $(this).attr("src")
fetch(api_url,{
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(curUrl),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
  })
  .then(data => {console.log(data)})
```

When the extension's code runs, I get the following in the console:
*Access to fetch at 'https://this-is-the-path-to-my-google-cloud-function' from origin 'https://www.reddit.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.*

I have tried multiple solutions, enumerated below:

1. I have followed the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors), such that by using Google's `gsutil`, I am able to confirm the following to be true for the bucket that my function lives in: `[{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, "method": ["GET", "POST"], "origin": ["https://www.reddit.com"], "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"]}]`. I have also tried having `["*"]` as my origin, to no avail.
2. I have also tried using in my fetch, `mode: no-cors` with no success.

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: does `<my-google-chrome-url>` allow CORS?

Comment: `Response to preflight` ... including handling `OPTIONS` preflight request

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Jaromanda X According to the gsutil commands that I ran, <my-google-chrome-url> should be configured as in #1 above. Are there additional permissions I need to make to my Python code or other?

Comment: read about preflight in that page ... specifically point 3, 5 and 6

Comment: Modern Chrome disallows cross-origin requests in content scripts so do it in the background script. To make a cross-origin request in the background script simply add the URL to `permissions` and use `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` as is, no tricks needed, see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Comment: Thank you @JaromandaX. I have tried points 3, 5, and 6 on the above-referenced page with no success. I am seeing the following in the Network tab under Request Headers: ```origin: https://www.reddit.com``` ; ```access-control-request-headers: content-type``` ; ```access-control-request-method: POST```. I have also added to my CORS methods so that it includes ```"method": ["GET","POST","OPTIONS"]``` , changed ```"maxAgeSeconds": 1```, and cleared my cache and I am still at a loss.

Comment: does your server handle OPTIONS request

Comment: I have added OPTIONS to the method, but have not configured anything else on the server side. I do not know how to configure OPTIONS on the server side otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you mention, the CORS error in this case seems to come from the Cloud Function.

In order to address this, you should configure CORS for the Cloud Function, not Cloud Storage.

CORS consists of the preflight request and the main request. In your function you should check for preflight request by checking if the request's method is OPTION and if so, respond the appropriate headers. Here is a sample:

```
def cors_enabled_function(request):
    # For more information about CORS and CORS preflight requests, see
    # https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request
    # for more information.

    # Set CORS headers for the preflight request
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        # Allows GET requests from any origin with the Content-Type
        # header and caches preflight response for an 3600s
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }

        return ('', 204, headers)

    # Set CORS headers for the main request
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }

    return ('Hello World!', 200, headers)
```

For more information, you can read the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests)